# Customize the JwPlayer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jwplayer

I need to add player to my Wordpress website to have for video playlist using HLS aes-128 encryption,
I think am going to use JwPlayer plugin the issue is I need to have specific design and specific arguments to display example:

- Having static playlist.
- Create kind of categorization title for group of videos for example in the image you can see title categorization ="Chapitre1" [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6JRG.png)
- Display duration for each video.
- Add some script make the playlist dynamic like the (show/hide) js function for example hide videos of category or show them by click [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIiIh.png)

So I'm asking if it's possible to have the same design and the same function using Jwplayer API ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

**`1.You can have static playlist`,**

- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1543546-example-making-your-own-playlist-sidebar
- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists
- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists

**`2.You can modify jwplayer skins,`**

- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2051702-jw6-building-jw-player-skins
- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406968-using-jw-player-skins

**`3.You can display duration for each video using jwplayer API,`** - [Check it out](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#jwplayergetduration)

**`4.Can we add some script make the playlist dynamic like the (show/hide) js function for example hide videos of category or show them by click ?? ,`**

Yes, you can do it using jquery. see the html after player gets loaded in DOM.